# Почему %glr-parser так редко используют?

Tags: bison

Пытаясь решить конфликт в грамматике узнал о `%glr-parser` который на всех неоднозначностях ветвится создавая копии парсера и решает проблему которая создаётся из-за невозможности парсера прочитать больше чем на один токен. Ища примеры использования glr не нашёл не одного серьёзного от этого появилось ряд вопросов:

1. Почему его так редко используют? У него есть какие то проблемы?
2. На сколько сильно ухудшается скорость разбора при его использование?

Comment: Предположим, что скорость и является проблемой.

Comment: Обычно легко можно превратить грамматику в однозначную путём небольшого изменения. Например, вместо неоднозначной `Expr ::= Expr + Expr | Expr - Expr | Term` используют леворекурсивную грамматику `Expr ::= Term + Expr | Term - Expr | Term` или праворекурсивную грамматику `Expr ::= Expr + Term | Expr - Term | Term` (соответственно для LR- или LL-парсера).

Comment: (То есть наоборот, LL- и LR-.)

Comment: @VladD вы привили пример в котором это сделать легко. а я приведу пример в котором сложно. например язык С++. нельзя без таблицы символов или glr парсера распарсить конструкцию scopeid::id из-за грамматике С++. Или всеми любимая неопределенность `x * y`. Но glr парсер позволит это сделать.

Comment: А неопределённость `x * y` разве устранима без помощи lexer hack? Или там выдаётся несколько деревьев разбора?

Comment: @VladD Вот тут пишут что у них GLR парсер для С++ работает без таблицы символов (см второй ответ, Ira Baxter, последние два абзаца): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243383/why-cant-c-be-parsed-with-a-lr1-parser/14852664

Comment: Ага, понятно, они пакуют каким-то образом два бинарных дерева в один результат. Спасибо за ссылку!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У GRL парсера к его большому плюсу(возможность разобрать почти любую грамматику и решить любую неоднозначность) добавляется много минусов.

Вот минусы которые я нашёл:

1. В [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/647313/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE/647625#647625) я привёл ограничение типа семантического значения. Не смертельно но неприятно.
2. Отложенность действий. Про это хорошо написанно в [доки](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/GLR-Semantic-Actions.html#GLR-Semantic-Actions)(см. 1.5.3.1).
3. Т.к. при конфликтах парсер начинает ветвится то невозможно использовать возвращаемое значение в лексер. Ну и отложенность действий тут тоже сказывается. С этим никак не справится.
4. Некоторые грамматики могут вызвать неожиданные проблемы при разборе конфликтов с которыми LALR парсер справляется хорошо. Тут нужен анализ грамматики из чего следует что не любая LALR грамматика подойдёт GLR парсеру.
5. Если после разбора разных частей конфликта оба парсера живы то [необходимо](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Merging-GLR-Parses.html#Merging-GLR-Parses) либо выставить приоритеты, либо произвести мерж. А мерж это всегда больно.

А по скорости сложно что то сказать т.к. работа GRL парсера не линейна и очень зависит от грамматике. Но приблизительная(очень приблизительная) сложность будет О(2^n) где n это количество конфликтов т.к. на каждом конфликте парсер ветвится на два других парсера которые в свою очередь могут тоже ветвится.

Напишите в комментарии если вам известные ещё какие то минуты и я обязательно добавлю их в ответ.

Comment: Минусов пока не скажу, еще не достаточно исследовал. Добавлю только, что GLR-парсер задействован в работе tomita-parser (https://github.com/yandex/tomita-parser/blob/master/docs/ru/dg/overview.md) и полагаю для решения 5го минусы при настройке проекта правилам можно повысить или понизить вес.