# Почему выбирается именно это правило?

Tags: bison

У меня есть правила. Приведу урезанный код.

```
translation_unit
    :declaration_seq_opt;

declaration_seq_opt:
    |declaration_seq;

declaration_seq
    :declaration
    |declaration_seq declaration;

declaration
    :block_declaration
    |linkage_specification
    ;

block_declaration
    :simple_declaration
    ;

simple_declaration
    :decl_specifier_seq identifier ';'
    ;

decl_specifier_seq_opt
    :
    |decl_specifier_seq
    ;

decl_specifier_seq
    :decl_specifier_seq_opt decl_specifier
    ;

decl_specifier
    :storage_class_specifier
    |type_specifier
    ;

storage_class_specifier
    :EXTERN
    ;

type_specifier
    :simple_type_specifier
    ;

simple_type_specifier
    :INT
    ;

identifier
    :ID
    ;

string_literal
    :STRING
    ;

linkage_specification:
    EXTERN string_literal '{' declaration_seq_opt '}'
    | EXTERN string_literal declaration
    ;
```

на тексте `extern int a1;` кидает ошибку `syntax error, unexpected INT, expecting STRING`.

Как я понимаю синтаксический анализатор хочет STRING т.к. пошёл по правилу **linkage_specification** но есть же правило **block_declaration** в котором и должна разбираться эта строка но он упорно идёт в **linkage_specification** и я не понимаю почему.

Проанализировал дамп bison-а.

Лог работы:

```
Starting parse
Entering state 0
Reading a token: Next token is token EXTERN ()
Shifting token EXTERN ()
Entering state 3
Reading a token: Next token is token INT ()
Error: popping token EXTERN ()
Stack now 0
Cleanup: discarding lookahead token INT ()
```

Выризка из дампа:

```
State 0

    0 $accept: . translation_unit $end
    1 translation_unit: . declaration_seq_opt
    2 declaration_seq_opt: . %empty  [$end]
    3                    | . declaration_seq
    4 declaration_seq: . declaration
    5                | . declaration_seq declaration
    6 declaration: . block_declaration
    7            | . linkage_specification
    8 block_declaration: . simple_declaration
    9 simple_declaration: . decl_specifier_seq identifier ';'
   10 decl_specifier_seq_opt: . %empty  [EXTERN, INT]
   11                       | . decl_specifier_seq
   12 decl_specifier_seq: . decl_specifier_seq_opt decl_specifier
   20 linkage_specification: . EXTERN string_literal '{' declaration_seq_opt '}'
   21                      | . EXTERN string_literal declaration

    EXTERN  сдвиг, и переход в состояние 1

    EXTERN    [вывод с использованием правила 10 (decl_specifier_seq_opt)]
    INT       вывод с использованием правила 10 (decl_specifier_seq_opt)
    $default  вывод с использованием правила 2 (declaration_seq_opt)

    translation_unit        переход в состояние 2
    declaration_seq_opt     переход в состояние 3
    declaration_seq         переход в состояние 4
    declaration             переход в состояние 5
    block_declaration       переход в состояние 6
    simple_declaration      переход в состояние 7
    decl_specifier_seq_opt  переход в состояние 8
    decl_specifier_seq      переход в состояние 9
    linkage_specification   переход в состояние 10


State 1

   19 string_literal: . STRING
   20 linkage_specification: EXTERN . string_literal '{' declaration_seq_opt '}'
   21                      | EXTERN . string_literal declaration

    STRING  сдвиг, и переход в состояние 11

    string_literal  переход в состояние 12


State 2

    0 $accept: translation_unit . $end

    $end  сдвиг, и переход в состояние 13


State 3

    1 translation_unit: declaration_seq_opt .

    $default  вывод с использованием правила 1 (translation_unit)
```

Включён glr дерективой `%glr-parser`. Согласно доке это всё что нужно. Но у меня `%skeleton "lalr1.cc"`, а в вопросе ниже говорят о `%skeleton "glr.cc"` но с этим скилетом у меня не компилится с ошибками:

```
ParserC.cpp:1149:13: error: object of type 'yyGLRStackItem' cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted
      *yyp1 = *yyp0;
            ^
ParserC.cpp:722:14: note: copy assignment operator of 'yyGLRStackItem' is implicitly deleted because field 'yystate' has a deleted copy assignment operator
  yyGLRState yystate;
             ^
ParserC.cpp:691:5: note: copy assignment operator of 'yyGLRState' is implicitly deleted because field 'yysemantics' has a deleted copy assignment operator
  } yysemantics;
    ^
ParserC.cpp:690:13: note: copy assignment operator of '' is implicitly deleted because variant field 'yysval' has a non-trivial copy assignment operator
    YYSTYPE yysval;
            ^
ParserC.cpp:1371:22: error: call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of 'yyGLRStackItem [6]'
      yyGLRStackItem yyrhsVals[YYMAXRHS + YYMAXLEFT + 1];
                     ^
ParserC.cpp:722:14: note: default constructor of 'yyGLRStackItem' is implicitly deleted because field 'yystate' has a deleted default constructor
  yyGLRState yystate;
             ^
ParserC.cpp:691:5: note: default constructor of 'yyGLRState' is implicitly deleted because field 'yysemantics' has a deleted default constructor
  } yysemantics;
    ^
ParserC.cpp:690:13: note: default constructor of '' is implicitly deleted because variant field 'yysval' has a non-trivial default constructor
    YYSTYPE yysval;
            ^
ParserC.cpp:1640:18: error: call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of 'yyGLRStackItem [6]'
  yyGLRStackItem yyrhsVals[YYMAXRHS + YYMAXLEFT + 1];
                 ^
ParserC.cpp:722:14: note: default constructor of 'yyGLRStackItem' is implicitly deleted because field 'yystate' has a deleted default constructor
  yyGLRState yystate;
             ^
ParserC.cpp:691:5: note: default constructor of 'yyGLRState' is implicitly deleted because field 'yysemantics' has a deleted default constructor
  } yysemantics;
    ^
ParserC.cpp:690:13: note: default constructor of '' is implicitly deleted because variant field 'yysval' has a non-trivial default constructor
    YYSTYPE yysval;
            ^
ParserC.cpp:1675:14: error: call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of 'yyGLRState'
  yyGLRState yyleftmost_state;
             ^
ParserC.cpp:691:5: note: default constructor of 'yyGLRState' is implicitly deleted because field 'yysemantics' has a deleted default constructor
  } yysemantics;
    ^
ParserC.cpp:690:13: note: default constructor of '' is implicitly deleted because variant field 'yysval' has a non-trivial default constructor
    YYSTYPE yysval;
            ^
ParserC.cpp:1862:37: error: object of type 'yyGLRState' cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted
      yystackp->yynextFree->yystate = *yyr;
                                    ^
ParserC.cpp:691:5: note: copy assignment operator of 'yyGLRState' is implicitly deleted because field 'yysemantics' has a deleted copy assignment operator
  } yysemantics;
    ^
ParserC.cpp:690:13: note: copy assignment operator of '' is implicitly deleted because variant field 'yysval' has a non-trivial copy assignment operator
    YYSTYPE yysval;
```

Если glr действительно не работает то эта ошибка логична т.к. парсер пытается разрешить конфликт сдвига/свёртка в пользу сдвига и игнорит decl_specifier_seq_opt в котором нужна свёртка.

Нашёл [ещё вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526887/c-glr-parsers-with-bison) по похожей проблеме но на него нет ответа. Ощущение что glr вообще не работает.

Comment: А если правило `linkage_specification` на время вовсе убрать из `declaration`?

Comment: @VladD то всё парситься хорошо. сейчас исправлю вопрос с новыми данными.

Comment: Окей, то есть у вас reduce/reduce-конфликт, и вы хотите обойти его при помощи glr? Понимаю.

Comment: @VladD shift/reduce если быть точнее. да. сначала я просто не хотел править грамматику но теперь найти проблему это уже скорее дело принципа.

Comment: Название `lalr1.cc` как бы намекает, что с ним получиться не должно.

Comment: Подождите, а разве glr-парсер не ветвится только на reduce/reduce конфликтах? (Я не уверен.)

Comment: @VladD согласно доки https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/GLR-Parsers.html#GLR-Parsers то reduce/reduce и shift/reduce конфликтах.

Comment: Спасибо, не знал, почитаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это правило выбирается потому что парсер не **glr**, а **LALR(1)** т.к. это указанно в директиве `skeleton`.

Т.к. это **LALR(1)** то ошибка ожидаема потому что конфликт разрешился бы
в сторону **linkage_specification**. Оно соответвтвует *shift* в конфлиткте *shift/reduce* с **decl_specifier_seq_opt** (которое может быть пустым и соответствует reduce).

Для того что бы парсер стал **glr** необходимо указать `%skeleton "glr.cc"`, а ошибки возникают из-за того что тип не простой.

В [доке](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/GLR-Semantic-Actions.html#GLR-Semantic-Actions) (см. 1.5.3.3) накладывается ограничение на тип семантического значения. Он должно быть POD.

Comment: А нельзя ли тогда использовать указатель?

Comment: @VladD можно. указатели же POD. но в таком случае нужно очень скрупулезно относится у утечкам памяти.

Comment: Угу, я о том же, жаль, что нельзя смарт-пойнтер